# Program works but I still get a NoneType error Python Decorators

Tags: python, decorator, nonetype

So I'm very new and decided to try out decorators and basically it adds "Start" before showing the name, and "End" afterwards. Very simple, and it works, but I get a NoneType error?

```
def start_end_decorator(func):

    def wrapper():
        print("Start")
        func()
        print("End")
    return wrapper()

@start_end_decorator
def print_name():
    print ('Nero')

print_name()
```

here's the output:

```
line 13, in <module>
    print_name()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Start
Nero
```

I'm so confused? Should I just ignore it with maybe a try/except?
End

Answer (score 3):

The function `wrapper` doesn't have a return statement in it, so it returns `None`. Therefore this line in start_end_decorator():

```
return wrapper()
```

returns `None`. Your intention was surely to return the function, not the function's return value. Try changing that statement to this:

```
return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

A decorator has to return a callable object.  `start_end_decorator`, however, is returning the return value of `wrapper`.  Since `wrapper` has no `return` statement, `None` is implicitly returned.  `None` is not a callable object hence the error.

What you want is to return `wrapper` from your decorator instead of `wrapper()`.

Answer (score 0):

def start_end_decorator(func):

```
def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
    print('start')
    
    result=func(*args,**kwargs)
    
    print('End')
    
    return result
return wrapper
```

@start_end_decorator
def add(x):
print (x)
return x+5

result=add (100)
print(result)

O/P:
start
100
End
105

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).